# Place popup at bottom of screen (NOT at bottom of browser window)

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

my question is. How to alace a popup window at bottom of screen (NOT at bottom of browser window)?

Which property do I use for that?

Comment: Any screenshots on what you want?

Comment: Added an answer.. and then took extra notice of the "NOT at bottom of browser window" text. Since you are tagged 'javascript/html/css', i seriously wonder what you are trying to do.. You want web based scripting languages to do something outside of the browser window? If that is the case: impossible to do without extra software like ie. adobe air(which is no longer being developed)

Answer (score 2):

Properties of the screen are in `window.screen` and it contains data for the `availHeight` and `availWidth` amongst others.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen

As an example of how to use these to open a popup window at the bottom right of the screen: http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/56XG6/

Answer (score 1):

###Webkit-Notifications?
If you are looking for Webkit Notifications, then, use something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Desktop Notifications</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkNotifications() {
                if (window.webkitNotifications)
                    alert("Notifications are supported!");
                else
                    alert("Notifications are not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.");
            }
            function createNotificationInstance(options) {
                if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) { // 0 is PERMISSION_ALLOWED
                    if (options.notificationType == 'simple') {
                        return window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('icon.png', 'Notification Title', 'Notification content...');
                    } else if (options.notificationType == 'html') {
                        return window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('http://localhost/');
                    }
                } else {
                    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
            body {font-size: 10pt; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            p {margin: 5px;}
            a {color: #09f; text-decoration: none;}
            a:hover {color: #f00;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><strong>Desktop Notifications</strong></p>
        <p>Lets see how the notifications work in this browser.</p>
        <p>
            <a href="#" onclick="checkNotifications(); return false;">Check Notification Support</a>.
            Next <a href="#" onclick="alert('Notifications are ' + ((window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) ? '' : 'not ') + 'allowed!'); return false;">Check Notification Permissions</a>
            and if permissions are not there,
            <a href="#" onclick="window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(); return false;">Request Permissions</a>.
            Create a
            <a href="#" id="text">Simple Notification</a>
            or
            <a href="#" id="html">HTML Notification</a>.
        </p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.querySelector("#html").addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
                createNotificationInstance({ notificationType: 'html' });
            } else {
                window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
            }
        }, false);
        document.querySelector("#text").addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
                createNotificationInstance({ notificationType: 'simple' }).show();
            } else {
                window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
</html>
```

###Screenshot

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamai.net](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/7e963e54e3fc0bc8a40728937f515f0f03b4ce77/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f644a6b6a4d2e706e67))</sub>

***Note:** This works only in Chrome and other WebKit based browsers... For more info, see [Can I use Web Notifications?](https://caniuse.com/notifications)*

Comment: +1.. even if its not cross browser, its the closest that can be done to reach the poster's requirement.

Comment: I don't know what happened to my edit. I just posted `Note: This works only in Chrome and other webkit based browsers.` Weird. `:O`